# Show $f(x)=\int_0^x 1+\sin(\sin(t)) \, dt$ is increasing

Tags: calculus

I want to show $f(x)=\int_0^x 1+\sin(\sin(t)) \, dt$ is increasing over the reals.  Is this possible without evaluating the integral (not sure if I can even evaluate it)?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Tried integrating but that didn't work

Comment: How about differentiating? What's the condition on the first derivative for a function to be increasing?

Comment: Not a proof, but if you check the graph of $1+sin(sin(t))$ it is always positive in the interval $[0,x]$

Comment: Ah I see it now - thank you!  We apply the Fundamental theorem of calculus and show that the derivative of $f$ is always positive, hence $f$ is increasing

Comment: @SaranWrap, If you figured it out, I recommend you to answer this question yourself. I think it will help you :)

Comment: Appreciate the help @Atticus

Answer (score 1):

You might note that $-1 \le \sin(z) \le 1$ for all $z$, so $1+\sin(\sin t) \ge 0$. The result follows, for obviously integrating a non-negative function gives an increasing one.